# How can I invisible child class of an id in css?

Tags: html, css

Hi here's my code I want to make my div element with the class of "two" invisible. And I want to make that with css.

```
    <div class"zero" id="myid"> 
       <div class="one"> </div>
       <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The element div with the class of two is already invisible. Because you didn't add a height or a width and background-color. However, if you want to make something invisible with css, select that element and use the proprety display in css and set display to none or use the css proprety visibility and set it to hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#myid.zero .two {

  display: none;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="zero" id="myid"> 

    <div class="one"><p>ONE</p></div>

    <div class="two"><p>TWO</p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: this work but not when "myid" have class like "zero" in my edit

Comment: add the class "zero" after "myid" #myid.zero .two {

  display: none;
  
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the child selectors in CSS and use the `display` property to hide it.

```
#myid > two { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only direct childs (exactly inside desired element (#myid in your example)) use this syntax:

```
#myid>.two { display: none; }
```

but if you need all childs (direct and indirect) use this:

```
#myid .two { display: none; }
```